# Google Data Securuty Questions?

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-console, google-developers-console

im about to submit my first app and I don't really know how to fill the google security form. My app doesn't collect any data I know of. its just a simple app with information listed in it. You can also click some buttons that will take you directly to your phone dial screen, text message screen and email provider page to contact the number or email you clicked from the app. i made this functionality through URL launcher. However, users can email me from the app if they have any issues and of course I will reply them. I also have google admob on the app and I will hopefully use google analytics to view all these stuff. I don't have any login/signup screens or anything like that. App is completely free too. should I also state in my privacy policy that I collect data or I don't collect any? (im confused as to what counts as collecting data).
thanks

please how do I answer the questions below

Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types?

Yes

No

Is your app currently certified by an authorized lab, according to the Mobile Application Security Assessment (MASA) framework? Learn about how you should answer

Yes

No

Answer (score 0):

If the email goes through your app, I mean, you have an SMTP server who serves the email and the data is going to your app server then Yes, you are collecting data.

But if there is just showing information, any login, and not collecting cache, then virtually you are not collecting data.